# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found jdbc:oracle:thin

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to deploy a spring based web application in my local tomcat server. Below are my application details:

- Spring based web application (war)
- Tomcat 6 server
- Java 1.6
- Oracle DB
- Below are by jdbc configuration:

  Configuration for tomcat settings only.
  `javax.persistence.jdbc.drive=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`       `javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@coursesdev.cvbaybp20ew7.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:DEVCRS`
  `javax.persistence.jdbc.user=test`
  `javax.persistence.jdbc.password=test`
- I have also added ojdbc6.jar,ojdbc14.jar in my /lib folder

I deployed my war file without any issues. But when my application tries to connect to db it throws the error:"**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@coursesdev.cvbaybp20ew7.eu-west**"

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243):  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  jdbc:oracle:thin:@coursesdev.cvbaybp20ew7.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:DEVCRS
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:445)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:366)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@coursesdev.cvbaybp20ew7.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:DEVCRS
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.startUp(ConnectionPool.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@coursesdev.cvbaybp20ew7.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:DEVCRS
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    ... 97 more
```

I have seen a lot of post with the similar issue but am not sure what i am missing though.

Comment: `•I have also added ojdbc6.jar,ojdbc14.jar in my /lib folder` -->Which lib folder?

Comment: Please, correct your persistence property name as `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver`.

Comment: @ Jen  i have added it to my tomcat lib folder.

Comment: @ Ravi - Sorry i dint get your point. Is there anything wrong in the `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver` configuration ?

Comment: remove oracle6.jar add only oracle14.jar

Comment: @Sachin have you tried my suggession of removing oracle6.jar only and rerunning your project

Comment: The issue was with my property name. As mentioned by Ravi i changed the property from `javax.persistence.jdbc.drive` to `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver`.  Restarted my tomcat server and it started working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is depends on your building structure. Adding jar file to your lib folder is not gonna do anything.
You should add the jar file to your classpath.
If you are building your project by IDE, lets say eclipse, you should add it to .classpath file. If you are using Idea you should add it to your .iml file and etc.
If you are building your project by ant you should add jar address to your build.xml file.
I suppose you are not using maven.